# Android: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent

Tags: android, image, android-activity, android-intent, sd-card

I am getting an intent delivery error in Logcat, and app stops unexpectedly when I call this;

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
         android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI), 1);
```

or this for that matter;

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
         android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI), 1);
```

and then process it with;

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
            Intent intent) {
  super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);

if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

    Uri contentURI =  Uri.parse(intent.getDataString());

    c = mSurfaceHolder.lockCanvas();

    tempCanvas.setBitmap(mDrawing);

    Bitmap tempBitmap = null;

    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();

    try {           
      InputStream in = cr.openInputStream(contentURI);
      BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
      options.inSampleSize=8;
      tempBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in,null,options);
        }
    catch (Exception ee) {
      tempBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                    R.drawable.icon);
        }

    tempCanvas.drawBitmap(tempBitmap, 0, 0, null);
    c.drawBitmap(tempBitmap, 0, 0, null);

    mSurfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
  }
}
```

Errors out with "app has stopped unexpectedly" with logcat showing;

```
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24768): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { act=com.htc.HTCAlbum.action.ITEM_PICKER_FROM_COLLECTIONS dat=content://media/external/images/media/185 }} to activity {com.example.colorbook/com.example.colorbook.Colorbook}: java.lang.NullPointerException

    Complete logcat as it finished gallery view activity and tried to return intent;
    02-03 10:47:22.042: DEBUG/MainActivity(22984): [HTCAlbum][MainActivity][onPause]: Begin
    02-03 10:47:22.042: DEBUG/MainActivity(22984): store mCurrentPosition_backup=0
    02-03 10:47:22.042: DEBUG/DisplayManager(22984): store mCurrentPosition_backup=0
    02-03 10:47:22.092: DEBUG/dalvikvm(22984): GC_EXPLICIT freed 1459 objects / 91880 bytes in 44ms
    02-03 10:47:22.102: INFO/AlbumMapper(22984): Create thumbnail for: /mnt/sdcard/workspace/Colorbook/res/drawable/fileload.png
    02-03 10:47:22.102: DEBUG/ThumbnailWorker(22984): [stopWorking] Stop working, now join #37, /mnt/sdcard/workspace/Colorbook/res/drawable/fileload.png
    02-03 10:47:22.102: DEBUG/AlbumAdapter(22984): set thread priority to normal
    02-03 10:47:22.102: DEBUG/AbstractViewGetter(22984): Raise getter prefetcher thread priority to normal.
    02-03 10:47:22.102: DEBUG/AbstractViewGetter(22984): Join getter prefetch thread
    02-03 10:47:22.102: DEBUG/AbstractViewGetter(22984): Getter prefetch join time: 2
    02-03 10:47:22.102: DEBUG/AlbumMapper(22984): cancel current decode operation
    02-03 10:47:22.182: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(24768): Shutting down VM
    02-03 10:47:22.182: WARN/dalvikvm(24768): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x400259f8)
    02-03 10:47:22.182: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24768): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    02-03 10:47:22.182: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24768): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { act=com.htc.HTCAlbum.action.ITEM_PICKER_FROM_COLLECTIONS dat=content://media/external/images/media/185 }} to activity {com.example.colorbook/com.example.colorbook.Colorbook}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    02-03 10:47:22.182: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24768): at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3734)
    02-03 10:47:22.182: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24768): at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3776)
    02-03 10:47:22.182: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24768): at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2800(ActivityThread.java:135)
    02-03 10:47:22.182: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24768): at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2166)
    02-03 10:47:22.182: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24768): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    02-03 10:47:22.182: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24768): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:144)
    02-03 10:47:22.182: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24768): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4937)
    02-03 10:47:22.182: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24768): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    02-03 10:47:22.182: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24768): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
    02-03 10:47:22.182: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24768): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
    02-03 10:47:22.182: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24768): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
    02-03 10:47:22.182: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24768): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    02-03 10:47:22.182: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24768): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    02-03 10:47:22.182: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24768): at com.example.colorbook.Colorbook.loadImageToCanvas(Colorbook.java:524)
    02-03 10:47:22.182: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24768): at com.example.colorbook.Colorbook.onActivityResult(Colorbook.java:231)
    02-03 10:47:22.182: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24768): at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:3931)
    02-03 10:47:22.182: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24768): at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3730)
    02-03 10:47:22.182: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24768): ... 11 more
    02-03 10:47:22.202: WARN/ActivityManager(97): Force finishing activity com.example.colorbook/.Colorbook
    02-03 10:47:22.704: WARN/ActivityManager(97): Activity pause timeout for HistoryRecord{46207010 com.example.colorbook/.Colorbook}
    02-03 10:47:22.742: DEBUG/Sensors(97): close_akm, fd=114
    02-03 10:47:22.852: DEBUG/MainActivity(22984): [HTCAlbum][MainActivity][onStop]: Begin
    02-03 10:47:22.902: DEBUG/dalvikvm(22984): GC_EXPLICIT freed 398 objects / 23264 bytes in 38ms
    02-03 10:47:22.902: DEBUG/MainActivity(22984): [HTCAlbum][MainActivity][onDestroy]: Begin
    02-03 10:47:22.912: DEBUG/OnlineDataCenter(22984): [HTCAlbum][OnlineDataCenter][unbindContext]: Begin
    02-03 10:47:22.912: DEBUG/OnlineDataCenter(22984): [HTCAlbum][OnlineDataCenter][unbindContext]: com.htc.album.MainActivity@46075ec0context size: 0
    02-03 10:47:22.912: DEBUG/OnlineDataCenter(22984): [HTCAlbum][OnlineDataCenter][unbindContext]: No more clients. release resources.
    02-03 10:47:22.912: DEBUG/OnlineDataCenter(22984): [HTCAlbum][OnlineDataCenter][unbindContext]: End 0
    02-03 10:47:22.912: DEBUG/ThumbnailWorker(22984): [stopWorking] Stop working, now join #-1, Decode Complete!!
    02-03 10:47:22.912: DEBUG/AlbumAdapter(22984): set thread priority to normal
    02-03 10:47:22.912: DEBUG/AlbumMapper(22984): cancel current decode operation
    02-03 10:47:22.912: DEBUG/AlbumMapper(22984): cancel current decode operation
    02-03 10:47:22.912: DEBUG/ThumbnailWorker(22984): [stopWorking] Stop working, now join #-1, Decode Complete!!
    02-03 10:47:22.912: DEBUG/AlbumAdapter(22984): set thread priority to normal
    02-03 10:47:22.912: DEBUG/AlbumAdapter(22984): Join worker thread in destroy
    02-03 10:47:22.912: DEBUG/AlbumAdapter(22984): Join time: 0
    02-03 10:47:22.922: INFO/MainActivity(22984): mWorker finishes jobs at onDestroy().
    02-03 10:47:22.932: DEBUG/CollectionsActivity(22984): [HTCAlbum][CollectionsActivity][onDestroy]: Begin
    02-03 10:47:22.932: DEBUG/AlbColAdap(22984): [HTCAlbum][AlbumCollectionsAdapter][onDestroy]: Begin
    02-03 10:47:22.942: INFO/BatteryStatsImpl(97): notePhoneSignalStrengthLocked: 2->3
    02-03 10:47:22.952: DEBUG/AlbColAdap(22984): [HTCAlbum][AlbumCollectionsAdapter][onDestroy]: End
```

Line 524 is this;
c.drawBitmap(tempBitmap, 0, 0, null);

Comment: could you point out what line Colorbook.java:524 is?

Comment: Is it because the result of startActivityForResult(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
         android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI), 1); can only be processed in a thread?

Comment: It seems I can't lock and draw on SurfaceView, when catching activity result after having done; startActivityForResult(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI), 1);. Where as calling one of my other dialog activities for this app, I can draw to surfaceview fine. Strange

Comment: Yep! For some reason when I load the actual image into bitmap and push it to Surfaceview, AFTER I exit onActivityResult, image loads fine!?!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solution:

Draw the bitmap during SurfaceChanged, using a flag whether to load image.

Apparently SurfaceView is not ready to be drawn upon at that time, immediately after the MediaStore activity is returning selection