# Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=200, result=-1, data=Intent

Tags: android, android-activity

I want to call my child activity from main one. During this, I need to pass linkedhashSet to it.
In child activity,I want to perform some operation on this hashset, 
and on click of OK button of a dialog in child activity, I want to return this new linkedhashset to pareent.

Currently I am using following code in parent activity while sending original hashset:

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putSerializable("keyThumbNails", thumbNailsLnkdhs);

                Intent AndroidCustomGalleryActivityIntent = new Intent(parentActivity.this, childActivity.class);
                childActivity.putExtras(bundle);
                startActivityForResult(childActivity,200);



Log.d(LOGGER, "ChildyActivityIntent called ");
```

it is working fine.
I am able to recieve this hashset in child activity, i can perform operation on it.

I am trying to send new hashset by using following code:

```
 new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
          .setMessage(mymessage)
          .setTitle(title)

          .setNeutralButton(android.R.string.ok,
             new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
             public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton){
                 Log.d(LOGGER, "AlertDialog neutral btn");
//                 // the button was clicked
                    Bundle bundleToSend = new Bundle();
                    bundleToSend.putSerializable("keyThumbNailsOfSelectedImages", SelectedThumbnailsPathsLnkdhs);

                    Intent SearchWebForWallPaperActivityIntent = new Intent(AndroidCustomGalleryActivity.this, SearchWebForWallPaperActivity.class);
                    SearchWebForWallPaperActivityIntent.putExtra("RESULT",bundleToSend);
                    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, SearchWebForWallPaperActivityIntent);
                    finish();
             }
             })
          .show();
       }
```

this is shwon properly.

In parent activity I am using following code to recieve this hashset... This code has problem after "got bundle" is logged...

```
@Override 
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {     
      super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data); 
      switch(requestCode) { 
        case (200) : { 
          if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) { 
              Log.d(LOGGER, "inside RESULT OK");
              //Bundle revievedBundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();
              Bundle recievedBundle = data.getExtras();
              Log.d(LOGGER, "got bundle");
             // if(recievedBundle.isEmpty()){
                  //Log.d(LOGGER, "its empty");
              //}
              SelectedThumbnailsPathsLnkdhs = (LinkedHashSet<String>) recievedBundle.getSerializable("keyThumbNailsOfSelectedImages");
            Log.d(LOGGER, "ThumbNailsLnkdhs size in SearchWebForWallPaperActivity intent: "+SelectedThumbnailsPathsLnkdhs.size());

             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                       "ThumbNailsLnkdhs size in old intent: "+SelectedThumbnailsPathsLnkdhs.size(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

          } 
          break; 
        } 
      } 
    }
```

I tried alot of things, search for long to get it working.
But couldnt succeed :(
Can anybody have a look at this code and help me ??

Following is logcat traces:

```
03-11 00:24:20.310: D/ADITYA(3959): inside RESULT OK
03-11 00:24:20.310: D/ADITYA(3959): got bundle
03-11 00:24:20.341: D/AndroidRuntime(3959): Shutting down VM
03-11 00:24:20.341: W/dalvikvm(3959): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
03-11 00:24:20.420: E/AndroidRuntime(3959): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-11 00:24:20.420: E/AndroidRuntime(3959): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=200, result=1, data=Intent { cmp=com.practice.wallpaper/.SearchWebForWallPaperActivity (has extras) }} to activity {com.practice.wallpaper/com.practice.wallpaper.SearchWebForWallPaperActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-11 00:24:20.420: E/AndroidRuntime(3959):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3515)
03-11 00:24:20.420: E/AndroidRuntime(3959):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3557)
03-11 00:24:20.420: E/AndroidRuntime(3959):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2800(ActivityThread.java:125)
03-11 00:24:20.420: E/AndroidRuntime(3959):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2063)
03-11 00:24:20.420: E/AndroidRuntime(3959):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-11 00:24:20.420: E/AndroidRuntime(3959):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-11 00:24:20.420: E/AndroidRuntime(3959):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
03-11 00:24:20.420: E/AndroidRuntime(3959):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-11 00:24:20.420: E/AndroidRuntime(3959):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
03-11 00:24:20.420: E/AndroidRuntime(3959):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
03-11 00:24:20.420: E/AndroidRuntime(3959):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
03-11 00:24:20.420: E/AndroidRuntime(3959):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-11 00:24:20.420: E/AndroidRuntime(3959): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-11 00:24:20.420: E/AndroidRuntime(3959):     at com.practice.wallpaper.SearchWebForWallPaperActivity.onActivityResult(myActivity.java:198)
03-11 00:24:20.420: E/AndroidRuntime(3959):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:3890)
03-11 00:24:20.420: E/AndroidRuntime(3959):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3511)
03-11 00:24:20.420: E/AndroidRuntime(3959):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: Edited my question and added logcat trace. Thank you

Comment: hi adit, why you are  using `putSerializable`??

Comment: All I wanted to move this linkedhashset to child activity and bring it back. So used serializable. can this be a reason for above exception?

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

Draw the bitmap during SurfaceChanged, using a flag whether to load image.

Apparently SurfaceView is not ready to be drawn upon at that time, immediately after the MediaStore activity is returning selection

From:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/4891558/4339857